# Cómo saber el código de cada tecla del teclado para KeyEvent.VK_?

Tags: java

soy nuevo aquí y tengo una duda estoy realizando un proyecto en Java y necesito que se presionen algunas teclas como por ejemplo menor que(<), anduve buscando el nombre de la tecla para colocarlo en KeyEvent.VK..... y ahí poner el código de esa tecla.

No sé si me explique, espero alguien me pueda ayudar :c

Estoy utilizando la clase robot para presionar teclas.

Comment: Con una simple busqueda en google te sale , ademas de la propia pagina de Oracle... [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola Jose el siguiente pequeño programa te permitirá obtener por consola una lista con la relacion nombre_tecla --> código.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class KeyCodeGenerator {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field f : fields) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && !Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers())) {
                System.out.println(f.getName() + " --> " + f.getInt(f.getName()));

            } 
        }       
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver en tu caso se trata de VK_LESS --> 153

El listado completo es:

```
KEY_FIRST --> 400
KEY_LAST --> 402
KEY_TYPED --> 400
KEY_PRESSED --> 401
KEY_RELEASED --> 402
VK_ENTER --> 10
VK_BACK_SPACE --> 8
VK_TAB --> 9
VK_CANCEL --> 3
VK_CLEAR --> 12
VK_SHIFT --> 16
VK_CONTROL --> 17
VK_ALT --> 18
VK_PAUSE --> 19
VK_CAPS_LOCK --> 20
VK_ESCAPE --> 27
VK_SPACE --> 32
VK_PAGE_UP --> 33
VK_PAGE_DOWN --> 34
VK_END --> 35
VK_HOME --> 36
VK_LEFT --> 37
VK_UP --> 38
VK_RIGHT --> 39
VK_DOWN --> 40
VK_COMMA --> 44
VK_MINUS --> 45
VK_PERIOD --> 46
VK_SLASH --> 47
VK_0 --> 48
VK_1 --> 49
VK_2 --> 50
VK_3 --> 51
VK_4 --> 52
VK_5 --> 53
VK_6 --> 54
VK_7 --> 55
VK_8 --> 56
VK_9 --> 57
VK_SEMICOLON --> 59
VK_EQUALS --> 61
VK_A --> 65
VK_B --> 66
VK_C --> 67
VK_D --> 68
VK_E --> 69
VK_F --> 70
VK_G --> 71
VK_H --> 72
VK_I --> 73
VK_J --> 74
VK_K --> 75
VK_L --> 76
VK_M --> 77
VK_N --> 78
VK_O --> 79
VK_P --> 80
VK_Q --> 81
VK_R --> 82
VK_S --> 83
VK_T --> 84
VK_U --> 85
VK_V --> 86
VK_W --> 87
VK_X --> 88
VK_Y --> 89
VK_Z --> 90
VK_OPEN_BRACKET --> 91
VK_BACK_SLASH --> 92
VK_CLOSE_BRACKET --> 93
VK_NUMPAD0 --> 96
VK_NUMPAD1 --> 97
VK_NUMPAD2 --> 98
VK_NUMPAD3 --> 99
VK_NUMPAD4 --> 100
VK_NUMPAD5 --> 101
VK_NUMPAD6 --> 102
VK_NUMPAD7 --> 103
VK_NUMPAD8 --> 104
VK_NUMPAD9 --> 105
VK_MULTIPLY --> 106
VK_ADD --> 107
VK_SEPARATER --> 108
VK_SEPARATOR --> 108
VK_SUBTRACT --> 109
VK_DECIMAL --> 110
VK_DIVIDE --> 111
VK_DELETE --> 127
VK_NUM_LOCK --> 144
VK_SCROLL_LOCK --> 145
VK_F1 --> 112
VK_F2 --> 113
VK_F3 --> 114
VK_F4 --> 115
VK_F5 --> 116
VK_F6 --> 117
VK_F7 --> 118
VK_F8 --> 119
VK_F9 --> 120
VK_F10 --> 121
VK_F11 --> 122
VK_F12 --> 123
VK_F13 --> 61440
VK_F14 --> 61441
VK_F15 --> 61442
VK_F16 --> 61443
VK_F17 --> 61444
VK_F18 --> 61445
VK_F19 --> 61446
VK_F20 --> 61447
VK_F21 --> 61448
VK_F22 --> 61449
VK_F23 --> 61450
VK_F24 --> 61451
VK_PRINTSCREEN --> 154
VK_INSERT --> 155
VK_HELP --> 156
VK_META --> 157
VK_BACK_QUOTE --> 192
VK_QUOTE --> 222
VK_KP_UP --> 224
VK_KP_DOWN --> 225
VK_KP_LEFT --> 226
VK_KP_RIGHT --> 227
VK_DEAD_GRAVE --> 128
VK_DEAD_ACUTE --> 129
VK_DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX --> 130
VK_DEAD_TILDE --> 131
VK_DEAD_MACRON --> 132
VK_DEAD_BREVE --> 133
VK_DEAD_ABOVEDOT --> 134
VK_DEAD_DIAERESIS --> 135
VK_DEAD_ABOVERING --> 136
VK_DEAD_DOUBLEACUTE --> 137
VK_DEAD_CARON --> 138
VK_DEAD_CEDILLA --> 139
VK_DEAD_OGONEK --> 140
VK_DEAD_IOTA --> 141
VK_DEAD_VOICED_SOUND --> 142
VK_DEAD_SEMIVOICED_SOUND --> 143
VK_AMPERSAND --> 150
VK_ASTERISK --> 151
VK_QUOTEDBL --> 152
VK_LESS --> 153
VK_GREATER --> 160
VK_BRACELEFT --> 161
VK_BRACERIGHT --> 162
VK_AT --> 512
VK_COLON --> 513
VK_CIRCUMFLEX --> 514
VK_DOLLAR --> 515
VK_EURO_SIGN --> 516
VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK --> 517
VK_INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK --> 518
VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS --> 519
VK_NUMBER_SIGN --> 520
VK_PLUS --> 521
VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS --> 522
VK_UNDERSCORE --> 523
VK_WINDOWS --> 524
VK_CONTEXT_MENU --> 525
VK_FINAL --> 24
VK_CONVERT --> 28
VK_NONCONVERT --> 29
VK_ACCEPT --> 30
VK_MODECHANGE --> 31
VK_KANA --> 21
VK_KANJI --> 25
VK_ALPHANUMERIC --> 240
VK_KATAKANA --> 241
VK_HIRAGANA --> 242
VK_FULL_WIDTH --> 243
VK_HALF_WIDTH --> 244
VK_ROMAN_CHARACTERS --> 245
VK_ALL_CANDIDATES --> 256
VK_PREVIOUS_CANDIDATE --> 257
VK_CODE_INPUT --> 258
VK_JAPANESE_KATAKANA --> 259
VK_JAPANESE_HIRAGANA --> 260
VK_JAPANESE_ROMAN --> 261
VK_KANA_LOCK --> 262
VK_INPUT_METHOD_ON_OFF --> 263
VK_CUT --> 65489
VK_COPY --> 65485
VK_PASTE --> 65487
VK_UNDO --> 65483
VK_AGAIN --> 65481
VK_FIND --> 65488
VK_PROPS --> 65482
VK_STOP --> 65480
VK_COMPOSE --> 65312
VK_ALT_GRAPH --> 65406
VK_BEGIN --> 65368
VK_UNDEFINED --> 0
CHAR_UNDEFINED --> 65535
KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN --> 0
KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD --> 1
KEY_LOCATION_LEFT --> 2
KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT --> 3
KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD --> 4
```

Un saludo

Comment: Me ha servido, disculpe lo que pasa que estoy desarrollando una app En Android que simula algunas teclas del teclado, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de presionar en la app CONTROL + C en la PC me haga esa funcion? Estoy usando la clase robot (Ya tengo todo creado el servidor y todo y ya me recibe las teclas solo que aún no se como hacer que me haga esa combinación de teclas).  Espero que me haya explicado una disculpa, no soy experto en Java. Saludos.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, tienes una app en Android que simula algunas teclas de un keyboard y por otro lado tienes una app que hace de servidor en un pc. Es así? Y entonces, lo que haces es enviar combinaciones de teclas desde la app de android al servidor. Si?

Comment: Exactamente lo mismo, y tengo las teclas control y C en mi app de Android y quiero que al precionarlas en el servidor(la PC) me haga esa funcion que sería copiar, agradezco su tiempo para responderme, saludos.